# I want to Query w3school database

Tags: mysql

The database is at: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all . Particulary I want to get the list of customers who placed product orders on July 1996 from Speedy Express Shipping Company and were served by employees: Davolio Nancy and Peacock Margaret. The result should have:

- Name of customer, contact, address, city, postal code and country
- The orderDetailID they placed
- Contacts of the shipping company
- Product name, price and quantity
- Product name, price and units bought
- Category of the products

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
    c.CustomerName,
    c.ContactName,
    c.Address,
    c.City,
    c.PostalCode,
    c.Country,
    o.OrderDetailID,
    s.Phone,
    r.ProductName,
    r.Price,
    o.Quantity,
    g.CategoryName
FROM Customers c
JOIN Orders d
    on (c.CustomerID = d.CustomerID)
LEFT JOIN OrderDetails o
    on (o.OrderID = d.OrderID)
LEFT JOIN Shippers s
    on (s.ShipperID = d.ShipperID)
LEFT JOIN Products r
    on (r.ProductID = o.ProductID)
LEFT JOIN Categories g
    on (g.CategoryID = r.CategoryID)
LEFT JOIN Employees e
    on (e.EmployeeID = d.EmployeeID)
WHERE s.ShipperName = 'Speedy Express' AND
    ((e.LastName = 'Davolio' AND e.FirstName = 'Nancy') OR
     (e.lastName = 'Peacock' AND e.firstName = 'Margaret')) AND
    EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM d.OrderDate) = 199607;
```

I get error which says:

```
ERROR 1: Could not prepare statement (1 near "FROM": syntax error)
```

When I remove the last condition (of extracting the date) as follows:

```
SELECT c.CustomerName, c.ContactName, c.Address, c.City, c.PostalCode, c.Country, o.OrderDetailID, s.Phone, r.ProductName, r.Price, o.Quantity, g.CategoryName FROM Customers c JOIN Orders d on (c.CustomerID = d.CustomerID) LEFT JOIN OrderDetails o on (o.OrderID = d.OrderID)  LEFT JOIN Shippers s on (s.ShipperID = d.ShipperID)  LEFT JOIN Products r on (r.ProductID = o.ProductID) LEFT JOIN Categories g on (g.CategoryID = r.CategoryID) LEFT JOIN Employees e on (e.EmployeeID = d.EmployeeID) WHERE s.ShipperName = 'Speedy Express' AND((e.LastName = 'Davolio' AND e.FirstName = 'Nancy') OR (e.lastName = 'Peacock' AND e.firstName = 'Margaret'));
```

the error disappears. So please how can i fix the year_month condition without getting error!

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I am using sql editor on w3schools.com

Answer (score 1):

One possibility here is that your version of MySQL, for whatever reason, does not support `YEAR_MONTH` being used with `EXTRACT()`.  One workaround here would be to use `DATE_FORMAT()` instead:

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(d.OrderDate, '%Y%m') = '199607'
```

To test whether you have an old version of `EXTRACT()`, just try running the following simple query:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM NOW());
```

If this errors out, then my conjecture is correct.